# QtCreator C++ : 2D matrix gives different results in different member function of the same class

Tags: c++, qt, matrix, qt-creator

recently I have been working on a two dimensional maze creator that creates a maze from a 2D matrix. And I used a boolean matrix with 1 representing a maze room, everything works fine but for some weird reason within the setRoomCode function every element of the matrix is detected to be zero. But the setRoomCode function is called after the the maze gets created within the matrix so some elements should be 1. Dunno where I went wrong, some help will be really appreciated... Thanks.

This is what the program looks like

[image]

//Matrix.h

```
#ifndef MATRIX_H
#define MATRIX_H

#include<QObject>
#include<iostream>
#include<time.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<QGridLayout>
#include"room.h"

class matrix:public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

 private:
    enum direction{LEFT, RIGHT, UP, DOWN};
    enum roomCode
    {
        N_A,ONE_L,ONE_R,ONE_U,ONE_D,
        TWO_LU,TWO_LD,TWO_RU,TWO_RD,TWO_LR,TWO_UD,
        THREE_LRU,THREE_LRD,THREE_LUD,THREE_RUD,
        FOUR
    };
    enum specialRooms{START, DIAGONAL, NORMAL_ROOMS};
    enum roomCodeArrayValues{TRUE_A, FALSE_A, NONE_A};

    bool **Matrix;               //The 2X2 matrix
    int curr_room_i, curr_room_j;          // variables for holding the current position in the matrix while iterating through it
    int first_room_i, first_room_j; // variable to store the first position
    int theSize;                 // Size of the matrix and no. of rooms

    QGridLayout *matrixGridLayout ;
    void createGUIMaze();

    int roomCodeArray[4];
    void categorizeRooms(int x, int y);
    void setRoomCode(bool leftPermission, bool rightPermission, bool upPermission, bool downPermission, bool x, bool y); //checking existing neighbors;
    int getRoomCode(int x, int y); // function to retrieve the room code

 public:
    matrix(const int theSize = 5);
    bool inMatrix(int valX, int valY) const;            // Out of bound check for an element
    bool allNeighborInMatrix(int valX, int valY) const; // Out of Bound check for an element's surrounding neighbor
    bool isAllNeighborOne(int valX, int valY) const;    // To check if a matrix element's LEFT,RIGHT,UP & DOWN elements are 1
    void setLocations();
    void printMaze() const;

    QGridLayout *getLayout();
    int getMartixFirstX();
    int getMatrixFirstY();

 public slots:
    void createMaze(int noOfRooms = 20);
};

#endif // MATRIX_H
```

//Matrix.cpp

```
#include "matrix.h"
#include <QDebug>

//The Constructor

matrix::matrix(const int theSize)
{
    srand(time(NULL));                     // seeding with system time
    curr_room_i = theSize-1;//rand()%theSize;               //(rand()%2 == 0) ? 0 : (rand()%theSize);
    curr_room_j = theSize-1;//rand()%theSize;               //(first_i == 0) ? 1 : (rand()%theSize);

    first_room_i = curr_room_i;
    first_room_j = curr_room_j;

    this->theSize = theSize;

//Matrix Initialization

    Matrix = new bool*[theSize];

    for (int i = 0;  i < theSize ; i++)
    {
        Matrix[i] = new bool[theSize];
        for(int j = 0; j < theSize ; j++)
        Matrix[i][j] = 0;
    }
   // Matrix[0][0] = Matrix[theSize-1][theSize-1] = Matrix[theSize-1][0] = Matrix[0][theSize-1] = 1;
}

// Creating the Maze

void matrix::createMaze(int noOfRooms)
{
    if(noOfRooms > theSize*theSize)
        {std::cout<<"Room Overflow!!!!!"<<std::endl; return;}

    Matrix[curr_room_i][curr_room_j] = 1;                                    // First maze room initialization
    srand(time(NULL));

    while(noOfRooms > 1)                                           //greater than 1 because first location is already initialized before reaching the loop
    {
        if (allNeighborInMatrix(curr_room_i,curr_room_j) && !isAllNeighborOne(curr_room_i, curr_room_j))
        {
             switch(rand()%4)
             {
                 case LEFT: if(Matrix[curr_room_i][curr_room_j-1] == 0){Matrix[curr_room_i][--curr_room_j] = 1; noOfRooms--;} break;
                 case RIGHT:if(Matrix[curr_room_i][curr_room_j+1] == 0){Matrix[curr_room_i][++curr_room_j] = 1; noOfRooms--;} break;
                 case UP:   if(Matrix[curr_room_i-1][curr_room_j] == 0){Matrix[--curr_room_i][curr_room_j] = 1; noOfRooms--;} break;
                 case DOWN: if(Matrix[curr_room_i+1][curr_room_j] == 0){Matrix[++curr_room_i][curr_room_j] = 1; noOfRooms--;} break;
                 default: std::cout<<"Invalid Direction !!!";
             }
        }
        else
        {
            switch(rand()%4)
             {
                 case LEFT: if (curr_room_j-1 >= 0)
                            {
                                if(Matrix[curr_room_i][curr_room_j-1] == 0) noOfRooms--;
                                Matrix[curr_room_i][--curr_room_j] = 1;
                            }break;
                 case RIGHT: if (curr_room_j+1 < theSize)
                            {
                                if(Matrix[curr_room_i][curr_room_j+1] == 0) noOfRooms--;
                                Matrix[curr_room_i][++curr_room_j] = 1;
                            }break;
                 case UP:    if (curr_room_i-1 >= 0)
                            {
                                if(Matrix[curr_room_i-1][curr_room_j] == 0) noOfRooms--;
                                Matrix[--curr_room_i][curr_room_j] = 1;
                            }break;
                 case DOWN:  if (curr_room_i+1 < theSize)
                            {
                                if(Matrix[curr_room_i+1][curr_room_j] == 0) noOfRooms--;
                                Matrix[++curr_room_i][curr_room_j] = 1;
                            }break;
                 default: std::cout<<"Invalid Direction !!!";
             }
        }
    }
    createGUIMaze();//creating the GuiMaze
}

//function to retrive the first position of the maze

int matrix::getMartixFirstX()
{
    return first_room_i;
}

int matrix::getMatrixFirstY()
{
    return first_room_j;
}

//Function to check if an element is in matrix

bool matrix:: inMatrix(int valX, int valY) const
{
    if(valX >= 0 && valX < theSize && valY >= 0 && valY < theSize)
        return true;
    else return false;
}

//Function to check if the neighboring elments of a an element are in matrix

bool matrix::allNeighborInMatrix(int valX, int valY) const
{
    if(valX-1 > 0 && valX+1 < theSize && valY-1 > 0 && valY+1 < theSize)
        return true;
    else return false;
}

//Function to check if the surrounding neighbors of a matrix element is one

bool matrix::isAllNeighborOne(int valX, int valY) const
{
    if(allNeighborInMatrix(valX,valY) && Matrix[valX][valY-1] == 1 && Matrix[valX][valY+1] == 1 && Matrix[valX-1][valY] == 1 && Matrix[valX+1][valY] == 1)
        return true;
    else return false;
}

void matrix::printMaze() const
{
    for(int i = 0; i< theSize; i++)
    {
        for( int j = 0; j<theSize; j++)
           {
                std::cout<<Matrix[i][j]<<" ";
           }
           std::cout<<"\n";
    }
}

//Function to create the GUI Maze

void matrix::createGUIMaze()
{
    matrixGridLayout = new QGridLayout;

    for(int k = 0; k < theSize; k++)
    {
        matrixGridLayout->addWidget(new room(DIAGONAL),k,k,Qt::AlignCenter);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i< theSize; i++)
    {
        for(int j =0; j < theSize; j++)
        if(Matrix[i][j] == 1)
        {
            if(i == getMartixFirstX() && j == getMatrixFirstY())
                matrixGridLayout->addWidget(new room(START),j,i,Qt::AlignCenter);
            else
            {
                matrixGridLayout->addWidget(new room(NORMAL_ROOMS,getRoomCode(i,j)),j,i,Qt::AlignCenter);
            }
        }
       // else if(Matrix[i][j] == 0) matrixGridLayout->addWidget(new room(0),j,i,Qt::AlignCenter);
    }
    matrixGridLayout->setSpacing(0);
    matrixGridLayout->setMargin(0);
}

//Function to retrive the grid layout representing the maze

QGridLayout *matrix::getLayout()
{
    return matrixGridLayout;
}

//Function to get roomCode

int matrix::getRoomCode(int x, int y)
{
    categorizeRooms(x,y);
    //four doors

    if(roomCodeArray[LEFT] == TRUE_A && roomCodeArray[RIGHT] == TRUE_A && roomCodeArray[UP] == TRUE_A && roomCodeArray[DOWN] == TRUE_A)
    {
        return FOUR;
    }
    //three doors

    else if(roomCodeArray[LEFT] == TRUE_A && roomCodeArray[RIGHT] == TRUE_A && roomCodeArray[UP] == TRUE_A && roomCodeArray[DOWN] == FALSE_A)
    {
        return THREE_LRU;
    }
    else if(roomCodeArray[LEFT] == TRUE_A && roomCodeArray[RIGHT] == TRUE_A && roomCodeArray[UP] == FALSE_A && roomCodeArray[DOWN] == TRUE_A)
    {
        return THREE_LRD;
    }
    else if(roomCodeArray[LEFT] == TRUE_A && roomCodeArray[RIGHT] == FALSE_A && roomCodeArray[UP] == TRUE_A && roomCodeArray[DOWN] == TRUE_A)
    {
        return THREE_LUD;
    }
    else if(roomCodeArray[LEFT] == FALSE_A && roomCodeArray[RIGHT] == TRUE_A && roomCodeArray[UP] == TRUE_A && roomCodeArray[DOWN] == TRUE_A)
    {
        return THREE_RUD;
    }

    //two opposite doors

    else if(roomCodeArray[LEFT] == FALSE_A && roomCodeArray[RIGHT] == FALSE_A && roomCodeArray[UP] == TRUE_A && roomCodeArray[DOWN] == TRUE_A)
    {
        return TWO_UD;
    }
    else if(roomCodeArray[LEFT] == TRUE_A && roomCodeArray[RIGHT] == TRUE_A && roomCodeArray[UP] == FALSE_A && roomCodeArray[DOWN] == FALSE_A)
    {
        return TWO_LR;
    }

    //two adjacent doors

    else if(roomCodeArray[LEFT] == FALSE_A && roomCodeArray[RIGHT] == TRUE_A && roomCodeArray[UP] == FALSE_A && roomCodeArray[DOWN] == TRUE_A)
    {
        return TWO_RD;
    }
    else if(roomCodeArray[LEFT] == FALSE_A && roomCodeArray[RIGHT] == TRUE_A && roomCodeArray[UP] == TRUE_A && roomCodeArray[DOWN] == FALSE_A)
    {
        return TWO_RU;
    }
    else if(roomCodeArray[LEFT] == TRUE_A && roomCodeArray[RIGHT] == FALSE_A && roomCodeArray[UP] == FALSE_A && roomCodeArray[DOWN] == TRUE_A)
    {
        return TWO_LD;
    }
    else if(roomCodeArray[LEFT] == TRUE_A && roomCodeArray[RIGHT] == FALSE_A && roomCodeArray[UP] == TRUE_A && roomCodeArray[DOWN] == FALSE_A)
    {
        return TWO_LU;
    }

    //one door

    else if(roomCodeArray[LEFT] == TRUE_A && roomCodeArray[RIGHT] == FALSE_A && roomCodeArray[UP] == FALSE_A && roomCodeArray[DOWN] == FALSE_A)
    {
        return ONE_L;
    }
    else if(roomCodeArray[LEFT] == FALSE_A && roomCodeArray[RIGHT] == TRUE_A && roomCodeArray[UP] == FALSE_A && roomCodeArray[DOWN] == FALSE_A)
    {
        return ONE_R;
    }
    else if(roomCodeArray[LEFT] == FALSE_A && roomCodeArray[RIGHT] == FALSE_A && roomCodeArray[UP] == TRUE_A && roomCodeArray[DOWN] == FALSE_A)
    {
        return ONE_U;
    }
    else if(roomCodeArray[LEFT] == FALSE_A && roomCodeArray[RIGHT] == FALSE_A && roomCodeArray[UP] == FALSE_A && roomCodeArray[DOWN] == TRUE_A)
    {
        return ONE_D;
    }
    else if(roomCodeArray[LEFT] == FALSE_A && roomCodeArray[RIGHT] == FALSE_A && roomCodeArray[UP] == FALSE_A && roomCodeArray[DOWN] == FALSE_A)
    {
        return ONE_D;
    }
    return N_A;
}

//Function to categorize different types of poosible rooms like rooms with two doors, rooms with three doors and so on

void matrix::categorizeRooms(int x, int y)
{
    if(allNeighborInMatrix(x,y))
    {
        setRoomCode(true,true,true,true,x,y);
    }
    else
    {
       if(x == 0 && y == 0)
       {
           setRoomCode(false,true,false,true,x,y);
       }
       else if(x == 0 && y == theSize-1)
       {
           setRoomCode(true,false,false,true,x,y);
       }
       else if(x == theSize-1 && y == theSize-1)
       {
           setRoomCode(true,false,true,false,x,y);
       }
       else if(x == theSize-1 && y == 0)
       {
           setRoomCode(false,true,true,false,x,y);
       }
       else
       {
           if(x == 0) setRoomCode(true,true,false,true,x,y);
           if(x == theSize-1) setRoomCode(true,true,true,false,x,y);
           if(y == 0) setRoomCode(false,true,true,true,x,y);
           if(y == theSize-1) setRoomCode(true,false,true,true,x,y);
       }
    }
}

//Function to set roomCodeArray
//The boolean arguments in this function decides whether it is allowed to check
//in a direction or not, directions being LEFT, RIGHT, UP and DOWN

void matrix::setRoomCode(bool leftPermission, bool rightPermission, bool upPermission, bool downPermission, bool x, bool y)
{
    //re-initializing the roomCodeArray
    for(int i=0 ; i<4; i++)
    {
        roomCodeArray[i] = NONE_A;
    }

    //setting the room code

    if(leftPermission == true)
    {
        if(Matrix[x][y-1] == 1)
        roomCodeArray[LEFT] = TRUE_A;
        else if(Matrix[x][y-1] == 0)
        roomCodeArray[LEFT] = FALSE_A;
    }
    if(rightPermission == true)
    {
        if(Matrix[x][y+1] == 1)
        roomCodeArray[RIGHT] = TRUE_A;
        else if(Matrix[x][y+1] == 0)
        roomCodeArray[RIGHT] = FALSE_A;
    }
    if(upPermission == true)
    {
        if(Matrix[x-1][y] == 1)
        roomCodeArray[UP] = TRUE_A;
        else if(Matrix[x-1][y] == 0)
        roomCodeArray[UP] = FALSE_A;
    }
    if(downPermission == true)
    {
        if(Matrix[x+1][y] == 1)
        roomCodeArray[DOWN] = TRUE_A;
        else if(Matrix[x+1][y] == 0)
        roomCodeArray[DOWN] = FALSE_A;
    }

    for(int i=0 ; i<4; i++)
    {
        if(roomCodeArray[i] == NONE_A)
        roomCodeArray[i] = FALSE_A;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function setRoomCode, the parameters x and y are boolean, but I suspect your meant them to be int, because your use them with +/- 1 with the Matrix (which is a 5x5 matrix by default).

This may be your problem, change them to int?

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was the problem... It's working fine now and I feel like a real stupid... So careless of me... Anyways, thanks again